# How to get dataframe index from series?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, series

Say I extract a series from a dataframe (like what would happen with an apply function). I'm trying to find the original dataframe index from that series.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]})
x=df.ix[0]
x


Out[109]: 
a    1
b    4
c    7
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Notice the "Name: 0" piece at the bottom of the output. How can I get the value '0' from series object x?

Answer (score 1):

you access it with the `name` attribute

```
x.name

0
```

take these examples

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print row.name, i

0 0
1 1
2 2
```

Notice that the name attribute is the same as the variable `i` which is supposed to be the row index.

It's the same for columns

```
for j, col in df.iteritems():
    print col.name, j

a a
b b
c c
```