# pandas: get the value of the index for a row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
                 cost       month  para
prod_code
040201060AAAIAI    43  2016-01-01  0402
040201060AAAIAJ    45  2016-02-01  0402
040201060AAAIAI    46  2016-03-01  0402
040201060AAAIAI    41  2016-01-01  0402
040201060AAAIAI    48  2016-02-01  0402
```

How can I iterate over the rows, and get the value of the index for each one?

```
d = { 'prod_code': ['040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAJ', '040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAI', '040301060AAAKAG', '040301060AAAKAK', '040301060AAAKAK', '040301060AAAKAX', '040301060AAAKAK', '040301060AAAKAK'], 'month': ['2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01'], 'cost': [43, 45, 46, 41, 48, 59, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 13] }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df.set_index('prod_code', inplace=True)
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print row.index, row['cost']
```

But I get this:

```
Index([u'items', u'cost'], dtype='object') 3.34461552621
```

UPDATE: This is the same as asking how to get the name of the index for a series, but phrased differently. Also though the *answer* is the same as another question, the *question* is not the same! Specifically, this question will be found when people Google for "pandas index of row" rather than "pandas name of series".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get dataframe index from series?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988903/how-to-get-dataframe-index-from-series)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
```

returns a `Series` for each row where `idx` is the `index` of the row you are iterating through. you could simply do

```
d = { 'prod_code': ['040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAJ', '040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAI', '040301060AAAKAG', '040301060AAAKAK', '040301060AAAKAK', '040301060AAAKAX', '040301060AAAKAK', '040301060AAAKAK'], 'month': ['2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01'], 'cost': [43, 45, 46, 41, 48, 59, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 13] }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df.set_index('prod_code', inplace=True)
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(idx, row['cost'])

040201060AAAIAI 43
040201060AAAIAJ 45
040201060AAAIAI 46
040201060AAAIAI 41
040201060AAAIAI 48
040201060AAAIAI 59
040301060AAAKAG 8
040301060AAAKAK 9
040301060AAAKAK 10
040301060AAAKAX 12
040301060AAAKAK 15
040301060AAAKAK 13
```

you can learn more about it [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas-dataframe-iterrows)

Answer (score 0):

use this to iterate over any value `df.ix[row_value,col_value]` for finding the column index use this function

```
def find_column_number(column_name):
    x=list(df1.columns.values)
    print column_name
    col_lenth= len(x)
    counter=0
    count=[]
    while counter<col_lenth:
        if x[counter]==column_name:
            count=counter
        counter+=1
    return count
```